# Is there a tool that can detect unused Java code based on a known set of "used" classes?

Tags: java, refactoring

I am looking for a tool that can take a large set of classes and search them for unused methods/variables when given a set of seed classes. My goal is to re-refactor the large set of classes so I can extract only the needed stuff — which is used by the seed classes — from it.

When I say seed classes, I mean a set of classes to be used as entry point for figuring out what is unused. For instance, if class A calls class B and class C calls class D, but the only seed class is class A, then class C and class D should both be considered unused classes. The tool I am looking for should be able to give the unused classes/methods/variables based on the set of seed classes. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: I was initially going to suggest Eclipse, but I'm not sure what you mean by "seed classes." Can you clarify?

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: +1, Eclipse automatically shows you unused class/methods/variables.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: a seed set is some set that you start an algorithm with, in this case building the call graph. Syn. (at least almost) with *root set*.

Comment: @lars, I'm familiar with the term in general, but I can't figure out what it means in this case. Naturally you'd need other classes around, to find out whether the ones you're interested are being used, but they don't really seem like seeds to me... I could be overanalyzing.

Comment: @Jonah, since you thought that was a reasonable interpretation, I added my comment as a full answer. If you weren't aware, you can actually customize the severity of the highlighting.

Comment: In my experience, if you have a real mess but are better off rewriting new classes to do the same thing.  You can create unit tests which show the old and new classes do the same thing to confirm this works.

Comment: @Torgamus: a seed set would be something like {`FooClient`, `FooServer`}, i.e. the set of classes you know a priori you're going to run. You could bootstrap this problem with a single class, but doing it on a seed set of arbitrary size permits optimizations :)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse's Java error/warning settings will help you find unused variables, through the **Unused local or private member** setting shown below. Unused method notifications should be controlled by a similar setting.

The **Unused import** setting, right above the highlighted line in the screenshot, should help somewhat with finding unused classes, but not on the scale you want. To use your example, I don't think Eclipse will recognize classes C or D as unused, as I don't think it can differentiate between the "seed group" and the "large group."

[image: screenshot of "unused member" option]

Comment: When I said seed classes I meant a set of classes to be used as entry point for figuring out what is un-used.  For instance class A calls Class B and class C calls Class D and if the seed classes is class A then Class C and Class D are considerred un-used classes.  The tool I am looking for should be able to give the un-used class/method/variable from the set of seed classes.

Comment: Hm, then this answer won't be perfect for you. In your example, I don't think there would be a way for you to mark class B as unused. It'll still help somewhat with the other aspects, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [CodePro Analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html)

Comment: my goal is to re-factor existing code depending on the usage from the seed classes and then generate a compact jar having all the needed stuff.  Today we have this large set of classes and some classes could be not used at all from the viewpoint of the seed classes and some classes are partially used (they could have other dependency which is unrelated to seed classes).

Answer (score 0):

Semantic Designs (my company) has such a tool for Java 1.4.  You designate a set of Java source files and essentially the seed classes.   It returns two results:

- A list of declarations (and their precise source code locations)
  that are useless with respect to the seeds
  (including the transitive closure of dead).
- A revised version of the supplied code, with the dead declarations removed.

If you like what you see in the first set, you can use the modified code.  If the first set lists something you thing should have been in the used list, add it to the seed set and run it again.

It assumes you aren't using arbitrary reflection (if you are, simply list those
classes that might be inspected by reflection. No, no easy way out of this).

We're working on one for Java 1.5/6/7 and hope to complete it this summer.  If someone was interested, we could make the 1.4 version available for experimentation.

Comment: we are using jdk 1.6 but if you have something for jdk 1.4 I certainly would like to give it a try.  Also, we are mainly using class (with full debug info) instead of java source for this task so if your tool can handle both java source and class that will be great.

Comment: @shean chang: contact me via email found at my bio.